# Android to Arduino Leonardo communication - sending and receiving commands over an OTG Cable

Tags: android, arduino

I am trying to build an Android Application and I have an Arduino Leonardo board that sends output via the keyboard write command. So far, I am able to receive the Arduino output on my Android device as keyboard input. I have an EditText text that just receives all the Arduino output and when the output sequence is over, I can then parse the EditText value easily.

However, the issue I'm having right now is sending data from Android to Arduino. I've done my research and the recommended/common ways of communication between Android and Arduino is via Bluetooth where the Android will send data to an Arduino with a Bluetooth shield. This is a viable solution, however, we have limited resources. I've also seen stackoverflow questions that involved an OTG Cable but those were communicating to Arduino Uno. It seems that those solutions did not work on Leonardo. I've also seen blogs wherein people in the comments section would ask on how to implement a cable based communication system between Android and Arduino Leonardo.

How can I resolve this problem? It seems like the communication interface/protocol across Arduino boards are different.

Also, as a side note, is it possible to use a different command to send data from Arduino Leonardo to Android aside from the keyboard write command?

Comment: from my side  i have also researched on it  and  find out the solution  by the example shown in ans  in which you can type the  massage  and then  send to the arduino

Answer (score 1):

This example show how to send String from Android to Arduino Uni via USB OTG cable, before sending you must be know about the

```
vendor-id="9025"
product-id="0067"
```

of `Arduino` have a look for this example

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.hardware.usb.UsbConstants;
import android.hardware.usb.UsbDevice;
import android.hardware.usb.UsbDeviceConnection;
import android.hardware.usb.UsbEndpoint;
import android.hardware.usb.UsbInterface;
import android.hardware.usb.UsbManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

 TextView textInfo;
 TextView textSearchedEndpoint;

 TextView textDeviceName;
 TextView textStatus;

 private static final int targetVendorID = 9025;  //Arduino Uno
 private static final int targetProductID = 67; //Arduino Uno, not 0067
 UsbDevice deviceFound = null;
 UsbInterface usbInterfaceFound = null;
 UsbEndpoint endpointIn = null;
 UsbEndpoint endpointOut = null;

 private static final String ACTION_USB_PERMISSION = "com.android.example.USB_PERMISSION";
 PendingIntent mPermissionIntent;

 UsbInterface usbInterface;
 UsbDeviceConnection usbDeviceConnection;

 EditText textOut;
 Button buttonSend;

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

  textStatus = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textstatus);

  textDeviceName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textdevicename);
  textInfo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.info);
  textSearchedEndpoint = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.searchedendpoint);

  // register the broadcast receiver
  mPermissionIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(
    ACTION_USB_PERMISSION), 0);
  IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(ACTION_USB_PERMISSION);
  registerReceiver(mUsbReceiver, filter);

  registerReceiver(mUsbDeviceReceiver, new IntentFilter(
    UsbManager.ACTION_USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED));
  registerReceiver(mUsbDeviceReceiver, new IntentFilter(
    UsbManager.ACTION_USB_DEVICE_DETACHED));

  connectUsb();

  textOut = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.textout);
  buttonSend = (Button)findViewById(R.id.send);
  buttonSend.setOnClickListener(buttonSendOnClickListener);
 }

 OnClickListener buttonSendOnClickListener =
  new OnClickListener(){

   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {

    if(deviceFound != null){

     String tOut = textOut.getText().toString();
     byte[] bytesOut = tOut.getBytes(); //convert String to byte[]
     int usbResult = usbDeviceConnection.bulkTransfer(
      endpointOut, bytesOut, bytesOut.length, 0);

    }else{
     Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, 
      "deviceFound == null", 
      Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }


   }};

 @Override
 protected void onDestroy() {
  releaseUsb();
  unregisterReceiver(mUsbReceiver);
  unregisterReceiver(mUsbDeviceReceiver);
  super.onDestroy();
 }

 private void connectUsb() {

  Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "connectUsb()", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
    .show();
  textStatus.setText("connectUsb()");

  searchEndPoint();

  if (usbInterfaceFound != null) {
   setupUsbComm();
  }

 }

 private void releaseUsb() {

  Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "releaseUsb()", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
    .show();
  textStatus.setText("releaseUsb()");

  if (usbDeviceConnection != null) {
   if (usbInterface != null) {
    usbDeviceConnection.releaseInterface(usbInterface);
    usbInterface = null;
   }
   usbDeviceConnection.close();
   usbDeviceConnection = null;
  }

  deviceFound = null;
  usbInterfaceFound = null;
  endpointIn = null;
  endpointOut = null;
 }

 private void searchEndPoint() {

  textInfo.setText("");
  textSearchedEndpoint.setText("");

  usbInterfaceFound = null;
  endpointOut = null;
  endpointIn = null;

  // Search device for targetVendorID and targetProductID
  if (deviceFound == null) {
   UsbManager manager = (UsbManager) getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE);
   HashMap<String, UsbDevice> deviceList = manager.getDeviceList();
   Iterator<UsbDevice> deviceIterator = deviceList.values().iterator();

   while (deviceIterator.hasNext()) {
    UsbDevice device = deviceIterator.next();

    if (device.getVendorId() == targetVendorID) {
     if (device.getProductId() == targetProductID) {
      deviceFound = device;
     }
    }
   }
  }

  if (deviceFound == null) {
   Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "device not found",
     Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   textStatus.setText("device not found");
  } else {
   String s = deviceFound.toString() + "\n" + "DeviceID: "
     + deviceFound.getDeviceId() + "\n" + "DeviceName: "
     + deviceFound.getDeviceName() + "\n" + "DeviceClass: "
     + deviceFound.getDeviceClass() + "\n" + "DeviceSubClass: "
     + deviceFound.getDeviceSubclass() + "\n" + "VendorID: "
     + deviceFound.getVendorId() + "\n" + "ProductID: "
     + deviceFound.getProductId() + "\n" + "InterfaceCount: "
     + deviceFound.getInterfaceCount();
   textInfo.setText(s);

   // Search for UsbInterface with Endpoint of USB_ENDPOINT_XFER_BULK,
   // and direction USB_DIR_OUT and USB_DIR_IN

   for (int i = 0; i < deviceFound.getInterfaceCount(); i++) {
    UsbInterface usbif = deviceFound.getInterface(i);

    UsbEndpoint tOut = null;
    UsbEndpoint tIn = null;

    int tEndpointCnt = usbif.getEndpointCount();
    if (tEndpointCnt >= 2) {
     for (int j = 0; j < tEndpointCnt; j++) {
      if (usbif.getEndpoint(j).getType() == UsbConstants.USB_ENDPOINT_XFER_BULK) {
       if (usbif.getEndpoint(j).getDirection() == UsbConstants.USB_DIR_OUT) {
        tOut = usbif.getEndpoint(j);
       } else if (usbif.getEndpoint(j).getDirection() == UsbConstants.USB_DIR_IN) {
        tIn = usbif.getEndpoint(j);
       }
      }
     }

     if (tOut != null && tIn != null) {
      // This interface have both USB_DIR_OUT
      // and USB_DIR_IN of USB_ENDPOINT_XFER_BULK
      usbInterfaceFound = usbif;
      endpointOut = tOut;
      endpointIn = tIn;
     }
    }

   }

   if (usbInterfaceFound == null) {
    textSearchedEndpoint.setText("No suitable interface found!");
   } else {
    textSearchedEndpoint.setText("UsbInterface found: "
      + usbInterfaceFound.toString() + "\n\n"
      + "Endpoint OUT: " + endpointOut.toString() + "\n\n"
      + "Endpoint IN: " + endpointIn.toString());
   }
  }
 }

 private boolean setupUsbComm() {

  // for more info, search SET_LINE_CODING and
  // SET_CONTROL_LINE_STATE in the document:
  // "Universal Serial Bus Class Definitions for Communication Devices"

  final int RQSID_SET_LINE_CODING = 0x20;
  final int RQSID_SET_CONTROL_LINE_STATE = 0x22;

  boolean success = false;

  UsbManager manager = (UsbManager) getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE);
  Boolean permitToRead = manager.hasPermission(deviceFound);

  if (permitToRead) {
   usbDeviceConnection = manager.openDevice(deviceFound);
   if (usbDeviceConnection != null) {
    usbDeviceConnection.claimInterface(usbInterfaceFound, true);

    int usbResult;
    usbResult = usbDeviceConnection.controlTransfer(0x21, // requestType
      RQSID_SET_CONTROL_LINE_STATE, // SET_CONTROL_LINE_STATE
      0, // value
      0, // index
      null, // buffer
      0, // length
      0); // timeout

    Toast.makeText(
      MainActivity.this,
      "controlTransfer(SET_CONTROL_LINE_STATE): " + usbResult,
      Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    // baud rate = 9600
    // 8 data bit
    // 1 stop bit
    byte[] encodingSetting = new byte[] { (byte) 0x80, 0x25, 0x00,
      0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x08 };
    usbResult = usbDeviceConnection.controlTransfer(0x21, // requestType
      RQSID_SET_LINE_CODING, // SET_LINE_CODING
      0, // value
      0, // index
      encodingSetting, // buffer
      7, // length
      0); // timeout
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
      "controlTransfer(RQSID_SET_LINE_CODING): " + usbResult,
      Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    /*
    byte[] bytesHello = new byte[] { (byte) 'H', 'e', 'l', 'l',
      'o', ' ', 'f', 'r', 'o', 'm', ' ', 'A', 'n', 'd', 'r',
      'o', 'i', 'd' };
    usbResult = usbDeviceConnection.bulkTransfer(endpointOut,
      bytesHello, bytesHello.length, 0);
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "bulkTransfer: " + usbResult,
      Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    */
   }

  } else {
   manager.requestPermission(deviceFound, mPermissionIntent);
   Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Permission: " + permitToRead,
     Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   textStatus.setText("Permission: " + permitToRead);
  }

  return success;
 }

 private final BroadcastReceiver mUsbReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
   String action = intent.getAction();
   if (ACTION_USB_PERMISSION.equals(action)) {

    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "ACTION_USB_PERMISSION",
      Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    textStatus.setText("ACTION_USB_PERMISSION");

    synchronized (this) {
     UsbDevice device = (UsbDevice) intent
       .getParcelableExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_DEVICE);

     if (intent.getBooleanExtra(
       UsbManager.EXTRA_PERMISSION_GRANTED, false)) {
      if (device != null) {
       connectUsb();
      }
     } else {
      Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
        "permission denied for device " + device,
        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      textStatus.setText("permission denied for device "
        + device);
     }
    }
   }
  }
 };

 private final BroadcastReceiver mUsbDeviceReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
   String action = intent.getAction();
   if (UsbManager.ACTION_USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED.equals(action)) {

    deviceFound = (UsbDevice) intent
      .getParcelableExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_DEVICE);
    Toast.makeText(
      MainActivity.this,
      "ACTION_USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED: \n"
        + deviceFound.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
      .show();
    textStatus.setText("ACTION_USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED: \n"
      + deviceFound.toString());

    connectUsb();

   } else if (UsbManager.ACTION_USB_DEVICE_DETACHED.equals(action)) {

    UsbDevice device = (UsbDevice) intent
      .getParcelableExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_DEVICE);

    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
      "ACTION_USB_DEVICE_DETACHED: \n" + device.toString(),
      Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    textStatus.setText("ACTION_USB_DEVICE_DETACHED: \n"
      + device.toString());

    if (device != null) {
     if (device == deviceFound) {
      releaseUsb();
     }else{
      Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, 
        "device == deviceFound, no call releaseUsb()\n" +
        device.toString() + "\n" +
        deviceFound.toString(), 
        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     }
    }else{
     Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, 
      "device == null, no call releaseUsb()", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    textInfo.setText("");
   }
  }

 };

}
```

Create /res/xml/device_filter.xml to specify vendor-id and product-id.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <!-- idVendor=2341, idProduct=0043 for Arduino Uno R3 -->
    <usb-device 
        vendor-id="9025" 
        product-id="0067" />
</resources>
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.androidusbhostarduinouno"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.usb.host" />

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="13"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|orientation"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED"
                android:resource="@xml/device_filter" />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_DETACHED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

layout, /res/layout/activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.androidusbhostarduinouno.MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:autoLink="web"
        android:text="http://android-er.blogspot.com/"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/textout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/send"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Send"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textstatus"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textdevicename"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textStyle="bold|italic" />

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/info"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/searchedendpoint"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

I hope it will helps you